# bash scripting improvement

Tags: bash

I have created the following script that move old days files as defined from source directory to destination directory. It is working perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Your Source Directory"
read soure

echo "Enter Your Destination Directory"
read destination 

echo "Enter Days"
read days



 find "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec mv {} "$destination" \;

  echo "Files which were $days Days old moved from $soure to $destination"
```

This script moves files great, but It also move files of source subdirectory, that I don't want.
it should not take subdirectory files. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-maxdepth 1` to your `find` command so that it doesn't not go into sub-directories.

From the `find` man page:

```
-maxdepth levels
    Descend  at  most  levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments.
```

Comment: My find command should find   -maxdepth 1 "$soure" -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec mv {} "$destination" \;
or something ????

Comment: not working gives following error find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: Try: `find "$soure" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime "-$days" -exec mv {} "$destination" \;`